# How to get the sso cookies (Playstation Network) using python

Tags: python, logging, playstation

Not a programmer here, thought I might ask if you could help me fix a plug-in on GOG Galaxy. What it does is it opens a login pop up, and once you logged in, gets your library from the playstation/sony website.

It was broken before but people found out that by replacing the line `"return NextStep("web_session", AUTH_PARAMS)"` with `"stored_cookies = {"npsso":"npsso from https://ca.account.sony.com/api/v1/ssocookie"}` it would work (so basically login via browser to get a valid *Auth Token* directly from Sony). Now this method doesn't work anymore because this link gets an *HTTP429*.
Someone did link to another [Python File](https://github.com/isFakeAccount/psnawp/blob/master/src/psnawp_api/core/authenticator.py) in hope of someone being able to merge them but sadly, the home page of that github does say that we need the *sso token* to make it work so... no luck here. I also looked on the internet but every *PSN logger* I found in python is from several years ago and the problems getting the *sso cookie* only started around the new year.

So my question is, does anyone know how to get this token through the PSN API or something?
Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Here is the code of the plugin file :

```
import logging
import sys
from typing import List, Any, AsyncGenerator

from galaxy.api.consts import Platform, LicenseType
from galaxy.api.errors import InvalidCredentials
from galaxy.api.plugin import Plugin, create_and_run_plugin
from galaxy.api.types import Authentication, Game, NextStep, SubscriptionGame, \
    Subscription, LicenseInfo

from http_client import HttpClient
from http_client import OAUTH_LOGIN_URL, OAUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
from psn_client import PSNClient

from version import __version__

AUTH_PARAMS = {
    "window_title": "Login to My PlayStation\u2122",
    "window_width": 536,
    "window_height": 675,
    "start_uri": OAUTH_LOGIN_URL,
    "end_uri_regex": "^" + OAUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL + ".*"
}


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PSNPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, reader, writer, token):
        super().__init__(
            Platform.Psn, __version__, reader, writer, token)
        self._http_client = HttpClient()
        self._psn_client = PSNClient(self._http_client)
        logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.FATAL)

    async def _do_auth(self, cookies):
        if not cookies:
            raise InvalidCredentials()

        self._http_client.set_cookies_updated_callback(self._update_stored_cookies)
        self._http_client.update_cookies(cookies)
        await self._http_client.refresh_cookies()
        user_id, user_name = await self._psn_client.async_get_own_user_info()
        if user_id == "":
            raise InvalidCredentials()
        return Authentication(user_id=user_id, user_name=user_name)

    async def authenticate(self, stored_credentials=None):
        stored_cookies = stored_credentials.get("cookies") if stored_credentials else None
        if not stored_cookies:
            return NextStep("web_session", AUTH_PARAMS)

        auth_info = await self._do_auth(stored_cookies)
        return auth_info

    async def pass_login_credentials(self, step, credentials, cookies):
        cookies = {cookie["name"]: cookie["value"] for cookie in cookies}
        self._store_cookies(cookies)
        return await self._do_auth(cookies)

    def _store_cookies(self, cookies):
        credentials = {
            "cookies": cookies
        }
        self.store_credentials(credentials)

    def _update_stored_cookies(self, morsels):
        cookies = {}
        for morsel in morsels:
            cookies[morsel.key] = morsel.value
        self._store_cookies(cookies)

    async def get_subscriptions(self) -> List[Subscription]:
        is_plus_active = await self._psn_client.get_psplus_status()
        return [Subscription(subscription_name="PlayStation PLUS", end_time=None, owned=is_plus_active)]

    async def get_subscription_games(self, subscription_name: str, context: Any) -> AsyncGenerator[List[SubscriptionGame], None]:
        yield await self._psn_client.get_subscription_games()

    async def get_owned_games(self):
        def game_parser(title):
            return Game(
                game_id=title["titleId"],
                game_title=title["name"],
                dlcs=[],
                license_info=LicenseInfo(LicenseType.SinglePurchase, None)
            )

        def parse_played_games(titles):
            return [{"titleId": title["titleId"], "name": title["name"]} for title in titles]

        purchased_games = await self._psn_client.async_get_purchased_games()
        played_games = parse_played_games(await self._psn_client.async_get_played_games())
        unique_all_games = {game['titleId']: game for game in played_games + purchased_games}.values()
        return [game_parser(game) for game in unique_all_games]

    async def shutdown(self):
        await self._http_client.close()


def main():
    create_and_run_plugin(PSNPlugin, sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```